# The terminal process "/usr/bin/zsh" terminated with exit code: 14

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

If you open it, it works ok for about 10 minutes, then it exits suddenly with status code 14.

[image]

What could be the issue?

I'm running vscode 1.65.2 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.json`:

Search for the line `terminal.integrated.shell.linux`, it says:

> This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile in `#terminal.integrated.profiles.linux#` and setting its profile name as the default in `#terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux#`. This will currently take priority over the new profiles settings but that will change in the future.(2)

In order to fix it you just need to follow these instructions.

Comment: How did you resolve this exactly? I am seeing this and adding User settings does not resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Has the exactly same problem

Solution:

added

```
export TMOUT=0
```

into the ./zshrc, and run the following command or restart the PC problem solved.

```
source ./zshrc
```

Root cause:

used command noticed that 14 is the signal SIGALRM

```
man 7 signal
```

Googled that,

> TMOUT
> If this parameter is nonzero, the shell will receive an ALRM signal if a command is not entered within the specified number of seconds after issuing a prompt. If there is a trap on SIGALRM, it will be executed and a new alarm is scheduled using the value of the TMOUT parameter after executing the trap. If no trap is set, and the idle time of the terminal is not less than the value of the TMOUT parameter, zsh terminates. Otherwise a new alarm is scheduled to TMOUT seconds after the last keypress.

this signal SIGALRM is only relatived the $TMOUT at zsh. Cannot find where is my computer been setted by $TMOUT, so just set the $TMOUT as 0 in ./zshrc. Problem Solved.